# abc tag... does it mean anything to you?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [`abc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abc) tag does not seem to add a great deal to me, or am I unusual in not seeing abc as Abstract Base Class immediately?

What should be done?

Comment: In Python, there exists [`abc`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) module.

Comment: As with all tags, if you hover the mouse over it you see a tool tip with the summary description, so I'm not really sure what the problem is!

Comment: Well... I was just unsure when I saw it in a post I was reviewing. Also philosophically if you need to look for more details on a tag is that tag doing its job? I would say it is worth the discussion. Clearly in the Python world it is super clear. in my C# life it is meaningless. I did not just delete the thing because I was not sure. I came here and asked for clarification which I got. Turns out there was no problem. Please feel free to carry on with your day now.

Comment: @Loofer: *all* tags require context. [tag:pelican] is a static website generation framework. Is that clear without the context? Do you know what [tag:plone] is? Or [tag:flex], [tag:cuda] or [tag:acc]?

Comment: Calm down guys! I just asked a question... the answer was "nothing" I accepted this answer! Onwards and upwards!

Comment: @MarounMaroun: You are welcome to narrow the excerpts scope. But please double-check it still describes the tags usage as good as before. Or retag those questions no longer fitting appropriately if you can make a good case for redefining the tag / if you are disambiguating. Reverted your edit for now.

Comment: @Deduplicator I don't understand, what was wrong with my edit?

Comment: @MarounMaroun: You changed the scope of the tag so that at least 28 of 78 questions would no longer fit. (This is based on assuming that everything tagged python did fit the re-definition, which is actually unlikely.)

Comment: @Deduplicator I see.. shouldn't we simply remove tagged questions that are invalid with this tag? As `abc` is a very specific to Python.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: There seems to be an r package, and some others. Also, it seems to be a catch-all for abstract-base-classes, which probably lead to naming the python package that way. Sure, take a look at the other questions too, and then decide whether python should really take over that tag for itself. Or whether it needs a new [tag:python-abc]. Or something else.

Comment: @Deduplicator Great, thanks for your note.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the Python [`abc` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html), so yes, it is kind-of obvious to a Python developer.

It *could* be renamed to `python-abc`, I suppose, but I don't see that much point in this specific case.

Comment: Seems there's a more than significant amount not related to the python abc module at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abc+-python+-python-3.x