# Disambiguate [abc]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

Disclaimer: while I personally don't think the tag in question should exist, this is not intended as a burnination request, but as an open discussion to choose a plan of action.

[Nearly 9 years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288586) there was some discussion of the [abc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abc) tag on Meta. This tag has developed some ambiguity over time, and I disagree with the original finding that a short tag like "abc" is justified by pairing it with a language tag. After all, we have tags like [python-import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-import) for a reason.

There are about 280 questions here, and almost all of them are tagged either [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) or [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x). All of these are almost certainly referring to either the `abc` standard library module (for creating one's own abstract base classes in Python) or `collections.abc` (which defines some useful ABCs and mixins for collection types - formerly defined directly by `collections`, which was a module rather than a package).

However, there are also a few questions about C++; one about C#; one about Perl (which seems to be about an external third-party library that implements ABCs) that are, as far as I can tell, about abstract base classes in other languages.

Then there are a few oddballs:

- Three questions also tagged [yosys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yosys). In this context, it appears that "ABC" means some kind of code generator and validator for Verilog and other HDLs, produced by the "Berkeley Verification and Synthesis Research Center". The tool is referred to [as `berkeley-abc`](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/berkeley-abc/berkeley-abc.1.en.html) and sometimes symlinked [as `yosys-abc`](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/yosys/yosys-abc.1.en.html).
- [One question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63307157/) about [some sort of tool for interacting with appbase.io](https://github.com/appbaseio/abc).
- [One HTML question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39114202/), [one Java question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664236), and [one Node.js question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28426499) where the tag seems to have been simply garbage. I retagged these (actually, for the Node.js question, it seems to have been part of self-vandalism that I rolled back). There was also such a question [about a Java web-app framework, but not actually about Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672367).
- And then the last, annoying one: [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42906326) that *wasn't* tagged [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) but *probably is* about Python - but where `abc` refers to a *file format* called ABC. (The `music21` library is supported by other programming languages such as JavaScript, and it's reasonable to ask about it in a language-agnostic way; but almost every music21 question is about using it from Python - to the extent that people answering the question typically assume Python when not otherwise told.) There are also probably other questions out there about reading or writing ABC notation music files, perhaps using other libraries. I don't know how they're tagged, of course.

In addition to this, there is an [abstract-base-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abstract-base-class) tag with over 100 questions (and also [abstract-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abstract-class) with over 5,000 questions).

---

My personal feeling is that there should not be an [abc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abc) tag. Specifically:

- Python questions in the existing [abc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abc) tag, i.e., the ones that are actually about a Python-specific library, should be renamed [python-abc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-abc).
- Questions generally about the concept of abstract base classes in other languages (particularly C++ and C#) should be retagged with [abstract-base-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abstract-base-class).
- Questions about files in ABC notation should be tagged [abc-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abc-format).
- Questions about the ABC tool for Yosys should be tagged [berkeley-abc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/berkeley-abc).
- The question about the Elasticsearch tool simply doesn't need a tag for the tool; it's just a [elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch) question.

Thoughts?

Comment: Clearly `abc` should only be used in questions about the songs of the Jackson 5, and thus are off topic.

Comment: [abc]: A Burnination Candidate

Comment: ... x, y, z, now we know our [tag:abc]s come and make a fire with me

Comment: There was this also this ancient PC computer called [ABC 80](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_80). In case anyone is still coding for those and have a question :)

Comment: Quick way to get this done. There's just [15 non python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abc+-python+-python-3.x) questions, so manually update those. Then get a mod to rename `abc` to `python-abc`.

Comment: @BhargavRao I mostly wanted to see if people agreed with my proposed changes, or had any better ideas, first. Seems like the idea is pretty well received.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because there were so few "exceptional" questions, and given the apparent support here (question score and comment feedback), I went ahead and retagged the remaining questions that were not about the Python ABC feature. I created [berkeley-abc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/berkeley-abc) and [abc-notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abc-notation) in the process. (`abc-format` somehow didn't sound right when I was typing it in.)

Regarding the appbase.io ABC question, I could only find one other question mentioning this tool, and that one seemed to be off topic anyway. So I simply removed the tag; it doesn't seem like there will be any long-term interest in on-topic questions about this tool. Hopefully the tags I created will have more use than this in the future.

I would now like to officially petition for [abc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abc) to be renamed as [python-abc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-abc).

Comment: Can we do that by creating the [tag:python-abc] tag, then creating a synonym request so that the [tag:abc] tag becomes a synonym of [tag:python-abc]?  Does that automate the change?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Moderators can rename tags in a much easier fashion, also a synonym actually means partly sticking with the [tag:abc] tag, given we want to move away from it that is not suitable.

Comment: Fair enough — it was a question.  My thought was that after the synonym was established (with the new [tag:python-abc] tag as the definitive tag), we could subsequently unsynonymize [tag:abc] effectively deleting it).  And most of that could be done without adding to the workload of the moderators.  But if it won't work or it is better to bother the moderators, then that's fine.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler a normal user can't remove a synonym and we'd end up needing a mod anyways if we do that.

Comment: Provisionally marking this as accepted, but hopefully we can actually get the tag rename to happen. Should I be pinging someone somewhere explicitly, or is this post sufficient?